# Passing Object Class array a strings to function

Tags: c++, string

I've been looking around for a fix to my errors but I can't quite find my case anywhere. So I have a function

```
int getUniques(Visitors info[], string address, string startDate, string endDate);
```

The function is going to take in my array full of Class Objects, and 3 strings. When I attempt to build, I get an assortment of errors. I'll list them all.

'Visitors' was not declared in this scope

Expected primary-expression before 'address' (same goes for other strings)

Expression list treated as compound expression in initializer

Anyone know what these mean and how to fix them?

EDIT: Lol I know so stupid of me, I fixed it now but I have other issues that I wanted to lead into. I am going to re-do my post and re-post in a little while if I still can't get my method to work.

Comment: You must not alter your question to some other unrelated question. If you still have trouble that you can't find answer for yourself after some reasonable time searching, you must ask another question, and leave this as is. The questions and answers on StackOverflow are archived for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those errors means the names `Visitors` and `string` were not recognised as types by C++ compiler...

In order to work, the declaration of your type `Visitors` must preceed the function declaration; either in the same source file or in a header file included with `#include` pre-processor directive.

Also, C++ `string` type is defined in the standard header file `string`, that must be included prior to usage, and the type is cotained in the namespace `std`, so you either need to use the full name `std::string` or declare you are using it with the `using` directive:

```
#include <string>
#include "visitors.hpp"

using std::string;

int getUniques(Visitors info[],
               string address,
               string startDate,
               string endDate);
```

and in the `visitors.hpp` file, your type definition (proably a `class`, but could also be a `struct`, an `union`, an `enum` or a `typedef` to some other type)...

```
#pragma once

class Visitors {
     ... // Your class definition.
};
```

Note that it is a bad practice to use the `using` directive in header files, because it will pollute the default namespace of the compilation units that include your header. If that is the case, you should use the full name `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

Is "Visitors Info" the declaration of an array being passed to the function?

If so, you need to declare what type of variable it is. eg. An integer array, or string array

So a corrected function declaration could be.

```
int getUniques(string Visitors_info[], string address, string startDate, string endDate);
```

Assuming I'm interpreting what your code is trying to do correctly.